# 24-hours time automatic regex

Tags: javascript, html

This is my code:

```js
let input = document.getElementById('f2f11c3');

input.addEventListener('input', addcommas, false);

function addcommas() {
  var v = document.getElementById('f2f11c3');
  var t = v.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
  var i, temp = '';
  for (i = t.length; i >= 0; i -= 2) {

    if (i == t.length) {
      temp = t.substring(i - 2, i);
    } else {
      if (t.substring(i - 2, i) != "")
        temp = t.substring(i - 2, i) + ':' + temp;
    }
    if (i < 0) {
      temp = t.substring(0, i + 2) + ':' + temp;
      break;
    }
  }
  v.value = temp;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="" maxlength="8" id="f2f11c3" />
```

But entered numbers can be greater than 24. Can you fully adapt to the time format?

Example: 23:59:59 and one more 00:00:00

Comment: Only using regex? I don't think so.

Comment: Why do you want to do *only* using regex? It's possible but extremely more complex compared to using basic arithmetic.

Comment: I think it will make my job easier. @VLAZ

Comment: @evolutionxbox first of all to provide the format I want

Comment: Regex is great for format checking, not for arithmetic. It won't make your job easier sticking to only using regex.

Comment: @evolutionxbox the only problem here is to ensure that the first 2 digits are not greater than 23 and the next 2 digits are not greater than 59.

Comment: That is not possible with regex. (At least in my understanding)

Comment: okey, Is there any other solution, just to make sure that the first two numbers are 23 and smaller and the other 2 are smaller than 59?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer

- Take the string
- Split that
- Use modulo operator to get the result

Example

```js
var time="24:70:65"; // Suppose we have this time

var parts=time.split(":");// Split the time with :

var part1=(+parts[0] % 24)
var part2=(+parts[1] % 60)
var part3=(+parts[2] % 60)

// Now to get answer in two digits you can 
part1 = ("0" + part1).slice(-2);
part2 = ("0" + part2).slice(-2);
part3 = ("0" + part3).slice(-2);

console.log(`${part1}:${part2}:${part3}`)
```

Hope this will work

Comment: This is just a logic you can apply accordingly. As per my understanding you want this let me know if you need something else

Comment: Thanks for your interest but that's not what I'm looking for. Automatically the first two digits will not be entered larger than 23, if entered, will round to 23. The other 2 households will be the same for 59.

Comment: So you can use this logic if users will enter more than 24 just do `%24`

Comment: and for two digit you can use padding

Comment: the user should not enter more than 23 and 59. The place I'm going to use is where I'll be required to show the user the alarm after how many hours, minutes, and seconds. you can only enter numbers, you can enter a total of 6 numbers and are grouped with 2 numbers.

Comment: `(?:[01]\d|2[0123]):(?:[012345]\d):(?:[012345]\d)` this regex you can try